# Command mapping utitly

Tags: command, utilities

I need a way to alias commands depending on their directory.
One of the use case is to be able to call different version of `ghc-mod` from Emacs depending on which project am working on. I can't see set it globally because files in directory a needs this version of ghc-mod and files in directory b needs another version.

I was thinking writing a simple wrapper script which will call the correct version of the binary depending on a config file specific to each directory (or project). I also needs this tool to be able to change argument name. However, I don't want to reinvent the wheel if such a tool already exists.
Afterall, I think this will be pretty useful and I'm sure someone has already needed it.